# Stochastic process starting from a Langevin dynamics

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, differential

I would like to derive a Langevin formulation starting from the definition of a given stochastic quantity (y(t) in my notation, where the first term is a Gaussian noise with zero mean and variance given below, whereas the second is a "memory kernel"). To obtain Eq. (184) for infinitesimal increments in dy I started writing the deviation y(t+\tau)-y(t) and its variance, but I do not know how simplifying Eqs. (186) and (187). 
Could you please help me? 
[in the attached picture there is an explanation of my computation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waMWq.png)Thank you so much!

Comment: I can't really parse all your undefined notation.

Comment: I wanted to add a picture but I realised only at the end that it was not possibile. You may refer to the link in blue "in the attached picture there is..."

Comment: I did. I can't interpret a bunch of the stuff you didn't define.

Comment: I am sorry for misunderstanding. I can attach another version just with the last, very important passages. I would like to simplify the last integrals (if possible) in Eq. 186 and in Eq. 187 as well for the variance. y(t) is a stochastic quantity which depends on the noisy part, \xi(t) with zero mean and variance given by the correlation C(t, t') + integral of a "memory kernel". I hope it is cleared now. Thank you.

Comment: y(t)= \xi(t)+\int_{0}^{t} dt' \; R(t,t') \langle s(t') \rangle = \xi(t)+\int_{0}^{t} dt' R(t,t') m(t') 
where $\xi(t)$ is a Gaussian noise with zero mean and variance $\langle \xi(t) \xi(t') \rangle= C(t,t')$.
The mean and the variance are respectively:
y(t+\Delta t)= \xi(t+\Delta t) + \int_{0}^{t + \Delta t} dt' \; R(t+\Delta t,t') m(t') \\
y(t+\Delta t)-y(t)= \xi(t+\Delta t)-\xi(t) + \int_{0}^{t+\Delta t} dt' R(t+\Delta t,t') m(t')- \int_{0}^{t} dt' R(t,t') m(t')

Comment: I think you should edit your post entirely (not in the comments), otherwise it is not understandable